# WooCommerce product collection issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I would like to ask how is it possible when i have  3000 variable products in an old woocommerce version eshop,  when i am trying to loop throught them that i get only 300 in return instead.

The following code is used by me in order to generate a product feed.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

Also the variable products are called variable because they support variation as I understand. That means that 3000 variable products are not 3000 "normal" products and instead the 300 that I see is the correct number of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are mixing up products (simple or variable) and product variations (that remain to variable products)... You need to display products (simple and variable) in your [**`WP_Query`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), but not your product variations.

With **`'post_type' => 'product'`**, you will get simple and variable products at the same time.

The missing argument is **`posts_per_page`** to be set to **`-1`**.

So your code will be:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    $loop->the_post();
    // set all product IDs in an array
    $all_product_ids[] = $loop->post->ID;
endwhile;

// Testing: Output the number of products in that query
echo '<p>Products count: ' . count($all_product_ids) . '</p>';
```

Then you will get all your products.

---

May be you can try to use a WPDB query:

```
## --- THE SQL QUERY --- ##

global $wpdb;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";

$product_ids_array = $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT `ID`
    FROM `$table_name`
    WHERE `post_status` LIKE 'publish'
    AND `post_type` LIKE 'product'
");

## --- TESTING OUTPUT --- ##

// Testing raw output of product IDs
print_r($product_ids_arr);

// Number of products
$products_count = count($product_ids_arr);
echo '<p>Products count: '. $products_count. '</p>';

## --- THE LOOP --- ##

foreach ($product_ids_array as $product_id):

    // Get an instance of WP_Product object 
    $product = new WC_Product($product_id);

    // Use the WP_Product methods to get and output the necessary data

endforeach;
```

Comment: Loic thanks for your answer i will check and get back to you!

Comment: i tried the correction as you suggested to me but the output is the same.
In the backend though there is 3000 variable products and 81 simple. So i am trying to understand what i have done wrong.

Comment: Thank you i added you @loictheaztec !